# Conversion issues between DateTime time zones

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, odbc, sqlbulkcopy

I am querying to a dataset with an ODBC connection using OdbcReader and OdbcCommands.

```
sourceData = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE created > '" + date + "';", connectionODBC);
```

The column `created` is read as a System.String object and in the format of `2019-08-03T02:47:19.794Z`. Ideally, all obtained rows have the column created as a date past variable `date` in the query. However, when using SqlBulkCopy the dates change.

Such as `2019-08-03T02:29:46.056Z` -> `2019-08-02 22:29:46.0560000`

or `2019-08-03T02:29:53.850Z` -> `2019-08-02 22:29:53.8500000`

Seemingly rolling back 4 hours. I am attempting to only transfer the data since a certain date, and it is failing due to a duplicate key error. Where using `2019-08-03 12:00:00 AM` as the `date` variable, is it still obtaining rows which, once parsed to DateTime, are past `2019-08-02 10:29:46 PM` instead.

The source is a third party distributor so I can't change the matter in which `created` is formatted. I do not understand the reason behind this behavior so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dates are store as a number in UTF.  The BulkCopy is not making any changes to the dates.  It is just displaying the dates using the CultureInfo on your computer.  So if you enter a time as UTF and then display the time without specifying the format you will get the local time.

Comment: Are you saying that SQL Bulk Copy is reading a string (that contains a Date Time stringified to a UTC representation) and it's magically transforming that into a different string representation of that Date and Time? That's surprising.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to use parameters.

Comment: re : jdweng : Okay yes I think that is what is going on. Is there any way to disable this change of formating with CultureInfo, without going line by line? Because through bulkCopy there is no apparent solution.

Comment: I changed the time on my computer and now it works, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Flydog57 It seems OP doesn't know how to specify the format; any chance you could elaborate?

Comment: @James.  What are the types of everything (in the database, in the C# code).  What time zone is your machine set to (UTC +/- N)?

Comment: @Flydog57 the machine usually runs on EST (UTC -5) and the database gives dates in (UTC-1). So changing the computer clock to (UTC-1) the error does not occur; when parsing to DateTime the time does not change.

Comment: using Unix timestamps can save you some datetime formatting headaches. 

MySQL: UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
PostgreSQL: CAST(EXTRACT(epoch FROM NOW()) AS INT)
MS SQL: DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE())
Oracle: (CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS DATE) - DATE'1970-01-01') * 86400